# ASUS Strix Vega 56 or 64

Tags: amd64, graphics

I'm in the process of creating ASUS AURA drivers for Linux. I'm hoping somebody here has access to a Strix version of the Vega 56 or 64 on a windows machine? If you do, would you please dump the `smbus`. This can be done using a demo version of AIDA64. Right click the bottom status bar and select "debug video -> dump ATI SMBUS" (or something like that).

I have the Polaris line of cards figured out, but Vega and Navi have thrown me a curve ball.